# Splitting a Python class among multiple modules using packages

Tags: python

I wrote some code in python as a class, but now I'm trying to prepare it for distribution as a package and I was having some trouble with figuring out how the different pieces should fit together.

So, as I originally wrote the code I had a class with a few functions in it, including an `__init__` function. I've now split each of these functions into its own file named with the function name, but I'm unsure where to put the **init** function, since it takes arguments. An example is below.

Original format:

```
class className(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
         self.arg1 = arg1
         self.arg2 = arg2

    def func1(self):

    def func2(self, arg3):
```

With a usage of:

```
import name

a = name.className(arg1, arg2)
a.func1()
a.func2(arg3)
```

Now the file tree is:

```
Name/
    /className
        __init__.py
        func1.py
        func2.py
```

And on to include the other functions. I would like to keep the same basic usage pattern as the original.

Now, the question I have is where that `__init__` function should go? Inside the `__init__.py` file? Somewhere else? The other issue is I wanted to put some imports in the `__init__.py` file; I know they should go in the `__init__.py` file, but I don't know how they relate to the `__init__` function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your class is so big you feel you need to split it into multiple files, you may want to consider some refactoring into separate classes.

Comment: I was actually under a mistaken impression of how the package needed to be created, but I think I've got it figured out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't split a class across multiple files. A package should contain multiple modules, which are files containing code (complete classes, functions, etc...).

The `__init__.py` file is run when the package is imported (although it's rare it is used to actually execute much code) and tells Python the directory is a package, it's not the constructor for a class.

A package (folder) should be a collection of packages and modules, while a module (file) will be a collection of code.

An example of a normal hierarchy:

```
- somepackage (Folder)
    - __init__.py (File)
    - somemodule.py (File)
        - SomeClass (Code)
        - some_function (Code)
```

As a final note, I say you can't split a class across multiple files - technically you could do this by monkey patching functions into the class or some other such weirdness, but you'd never want to as it would obscure your code a lot.

Comment: Thank you. This actually clears up some other things for me as well.