# Should I always use the most pythonic way to import modules?

Tags: python, frameworks, pygame, desktop, autoloader

I am making a tiny framework for games with pygame, on which I wish to implement basic code to quickly start new projects. This will be a module that whoever uses should just create a folder with subfolders for sprite classes, maps, levels, etc. 
My question is, how should my framework module load these client modules? I was considering to design it so the developer could just pass to the main object the names of the directories, like:

```
game = Game()
game.scenarios = 'scenarios'
```

Then game will append 'scenarios' to sys.path and use `__import__()`. *I've tested and it works*.
But then I researched a little more to see if there were already some autoloader in python, so I could avoid to rewrite it, and I found this question [Python modules autoloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068957/python-modules-autoloader)
Basically, it is not recommended to use a autoloader in python, since "explicit is better than implicit" and "Readability counts".

That way, I think, I should compel the user of my module to manually import each of his/her modules, and pass these to the game instance, like:

```
import framework.Game
import scenarios
#many other imports
game = Game()
game.scenarios = scenarios
#so many other game.whatever = whatever
```

But this doesn't looks good to me, not so confortable. See, I am used to work with php, and I love the way it works with it's autoloader.
So, the first exemple has some problability to crash or be some trouble, or is it just not 'pythonic'?

note: **this is NOT an web application**

Comment: Not to start a flamewar, but php really encourages bad habits. Go for option two.

Comment: As the author of the accepted answer in the linked question, I can only second klutt's comment and Nils Werner's (excellent) answer: Python is a totally different language with a totally different execution model and a totally different philosophy so forget PHP and learn to write things the Pythonic way.

Comment: Thank you. You're right and I like the way Nils put that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't consider letting a library import things from my current path or module good style. Instead I would only expect a library to import from two places:

1. Absolute imports from the global modules space, like things you have installed using `pip`. If a library does this, this library must also be found in its `install_requires=[]` list
2. Relative imports from inside itself. Nowadays these are explicitly imported from `.`:

   ```
   from . import bla
   from .bla import blubb
   ```

This means that passing an object or module local to my current scope must always happen explicitly:

```
from . import scenarios
import framework

scenarios.sprites  # attribute exists
game = framework.Game(scenarios=scenarios)
```

This allows you to do things like mock the `scenarios` module:

```
import types
import framework

# a SimpleNamespace looks like a module, as they both have attributes
scenarios = types.SimpleNamespace(sprites='a', textures='b')
scenarios.sprites  # attribute exists
game = framework.Game(scenarios=scenarios)
```

Also you can implement a `framework.utils.Scenario()` class that implements a certain interface to provide `sprites`, `maps` etc. The reason being: Sprites and Maps are usually saved in separate files: **What you absolutely do not want to do** is look at the `scenarios`'s `__file__` attribute and start guessing around in its files. Instead implement a method that provides a unified interface to that.

```
class Scenario():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def sprites(self):
        # optionally load files from some default location
        # If no such things as a default location exists, throw a NotImplemented error
        ...
```

And your user-specific scenarios will derive from it and optionally overload the loading methods

```
import framework.utils
class Scenario(framework.utils.Scenario):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def sprites(self):
        # this method *must* load files from location
        # accessing __file__ is OK here
        ...
```

What you can also do is have `framework` ship its own `framework.contrib.scenarios` module that is used in case no `scenarios=` keyword arg was used (i.e. for a square default map and some colorful default textures)

```
from . import contrib

class Game()
    def __init__(self, ..., scenarios=None, ...):
        if scenarios is None:
            scenarios = contrib.scenarios
        self.scenarios = scenarios
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice - except for the last suggestion which IMHO don't make sense in this context