# Use python file/function across multiple local projects

Tags: python

I have multiple python projects and each of them has a utility file, all of them with the same functions.

How can I set up some sort of local python library which I can import to all my local projects? I know rodeo has some functionality that you can use to designate some functions/files to be available across multiple python projects. Is there a way to do that outside of rodeo?

I do not want to create a library that is available through pip (since that would mean exposing it to everyone)

Comment: You can make a package and place it somewhere within PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Your assumption about pip is not true. It supports private package sources, for example git repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PyCharm, you can add directory with local utils to project as "content root":

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Structure -> Add content root
```

After that your utils would be available in project even if they're placed somewhere else.

If you're not using PyCharm you would need somehow add your external files to project's path. For example, [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114586/1113207).

Comment: thanks @Gerasimov, this is great to know. I guess though it won't be available on command line?

Comment: @user308827 you can try to add utils path to PYTHONPATH in command line, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4580120/1113207

Answer (score 5):

You can create a local python library by creating a python package.
It is as easy as putting a file named: `__init__.py`, into your utils lib.

You can read here more about the concept of [creating a python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215386/creating-python-packages)

And here [about how to write a good `__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files)

To finish, I just need to mention the PYTHONPATH, and an almost similar question [about importing from a parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951255/import-script-from-a-parent-directory)

Hope it was helpful for you.

Comment: I think the formatting disguised the correct file name. You meant, `__init__.py`. I would edit your post, but it won't let me with just those few edits.